# Is there a way to import a CSS file according to media in ReactJS

Tags: css, reactjs, media-queries

In a standard HTML file we can link multiple CSS's and then the browser will use the one that respects the media condition, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 600px)" href="mobile.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 600px)" href="web.css">
```

Is it possible to do the same in ReactJS ? like :

```
import './web.css'; //for web
import './mob.css'; //for mobile
.
.
.
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root')); //main app
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try conditional Import

```
if (window.innerWidth > 767) {
    import('./web.css').then(() => {
       console.log("Imported web css");
    });
}
else{
    import('./mob.css').then(() => {
       console.log("Imported mobile css");
    });
}
```

But I will recommend you to use media queries inside on CSS file which will be more handy in term of change

Comment: Thank you, it seems to work fine except that the changes aren't instant (page must be reloaded to RE-import the correct CSS in case the window's width changes), but it's not a big deal, I prefer this method over working on the same CSS file for both web and mobile. So thanks again for your quick answer!

Comment: Pleasure in mine always